# In the Chrome Devtools, is there a faster way to open "inspect devices" other than using the mouse?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, inspect

I would love it if there was a hotkey, or some other method I could use to avoid having to use the mouse to constantly re-open this window whenever I redeploy my app.

Alternatively, is there a way of re-using an opened device inspector window that I'm unaware of?

Comment: why do you close down the device inspector?

Comment: @Thesola10 Because it's not reusable after I relaunch my app

Comment: ah ok got it. tell me, is my answer suitable? how could I improve it?

Comment: @korona use `ctrl + shift+ C` or `ctrl + shift + I` for window

Comment: Have you tried F12 key ?

Answer (score 1):

`chrome://inspect` URL can be a good option.

But, what IS `chrome://inspect`? Well that's a global development tools page. It opens on the "Devices" tab by default, so that's handy.

I searched for a keyboard shortcut, but sadly I didn't discover any.

You could bookmark `chrome://inspect` and put a shortcut on your desktop by the way (except for Chromebooks, which is what I wrote my answer with)

From there, you can jump to inspection of any open page in your Chrome browser, which is nice too.

Alternative: When undocked, the Inspector will have the Console in the bottom. Well on the bar above the console, the leftmost three-dot menu has a direct "Devices Inspector" option.

Answer (score 0):

I use os x and use `Cmd+Opt+I` Hotkeys to open Inspector in chrome.

You can find more hotkeys [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts?hl=en#accessing-devtools)

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: I think the OP wants a shortcut that gets him directly to the Devices list